# Flatlist won't scroll

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

Im veryyy new to react native and I'm trying to build my first app. I'm trying to use a flatlist but it wont scroll. The items appear on the screen, however, they won't scroll. My app just basically inputs user input into the list. I tried removing any sort of flex styling, but still nothing. Pls help :)

EDIT: i forgot to add height to the parent view. Oops

Heres my code for the list component

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity,Modal,TextInput, FlatList, ScrollView } from 'react-native';


const AddUpdate = () => {
  const [posts,setPosts] = useState('')
  const [modal,setModal] = useState(false)
  const [array,setArray] = useState([])

  const AddToArray = () => {
    setArray(array =>[...array,posts])
    alert(array)
    setModal(false)

  }

  return (
   <View >
   <TouchableOpacity style = {styles.button} 
    onPress={() => setModal(true)} >
   <Text style = {styles.subTitle} >Post An Update</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
    <Modal 
    animationType='slide'
    visible={modal}
    >
    <View>
    <View style={styles.modalHeader}/>
    <TextInput
       multiline 
       placeholder="Write your message"
       style={styles.content}
       onChangeText={(val) => setPosts(val)}
       value={posts}
       maxLength={300}
    />
    <TouchableOpacity style = {styles.sendButton} 
    //onPress={() => setModal(false)} 
    onPress = {AddToArray} 
    
    >
  <Text style = {styles.sendTitle}>Post</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
    </Modal>
 
   
  {/* <FlatList //this is meant to be coded out.
  data={array}
 renderItem={({item}) => ( 
 
   <Text style={styles.postText}>{item}</Text>
 )}
  >
  {array.map((item,key) => (
     <TouchableOpacity>
      <Text key={key} style={styles.postText}>{item}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    
    ))}  
  
    </FlatList>
 */}

<FlatList
 data={array}
 renderItem={({item}) => ( 
   <Text style={styles.item}>{item}</Text>
 )}

/>   

</View>

  );
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 
  button: {
    elevation:8,
    margin: 5,
    top:-56,
    alignItems:'center',
    padding:30,
    backgroundColor:'#BEBEBE',
    borderRadius:25,
    
  },

  sendButton: {
    elevation:8,
    position:'absolute',
    top:20,
    right:10,
    left:200,
    alignItems:'center',
    padding:9,
    backgroundColor:'#8B0000',
    borderRadius:5,
    
  },

  subTitle: {
    fontSize:30, 
    color: 'white',
    marginLeft:-150,

  },

  sendTitle: {
    fontSize:20, 
    color: 'white',
    justifyContent:'center',

  },

  content: {
    flex:1,
    position:'absolute',
    fontSize:25,
    color:'black',
    top:130,
    right:20,
    left:20,
  
  },

  modalHeader: {
    height:90,
    backgroundColor:'#CC9900'

  },

  postText: {
    top: -60,
    marginTop:20,
    color:'black',
    fontSize:25,
    elevation:8,
    //alignItems:'center',
    padding:30,
    backgroundColor:'#BEBEBE',
    borderRadius:25,
    
  },

  item: {
    color:'black',
    fontSize:25,
    
  },


  
});

export default AddUpdate;
```

heres my code for App.js

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { FlatList,  StyleSheet, Text,  View} from 'react-native';
import AddUpdate from  './components/AddUpdate';


export default function App() {

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
    <View style = {styles.header}/>
    <View style= {{backgroundColor:'#fff'}}/>
      <Text style={styles.title}> Updates!</Text>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
      <AddUpdate/>
  
      </View>
    
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
   /// flex: 1,
   /// flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'stretch',
  //  paddingTop:30, 
  },
  header: {
    height:220, 
    backgroundColor:'#8B0000',
    borderBottomLeftRadius:55,
    borderBottomRightRadius:55,
  },

  title: {
    fontWeight:'bold',
    fontSize: 40,
    color:'#fff',
    textAlign:'center',
    top:-120,
  },

 
});
```

Comment: Can you try my solution?

Answer (score 1):

```
contentContainerStyle={{
    flexGrow: 1,
    }}
```

Add this to Flatlist
So in total it would look like this:

```
<FlatList
 data={array}
contentContainerStyle={{
    flexGrow: 1,
    }}
 renderItem={({item}) => ( 
   <Text style={styles.item}>{item}</Text>
 )}

/>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: i tried this as well. No luck, it shows my items, but still no scrolling

Answer (score 0):

Please enclose your Flatlist within a scrollview

```
import { ScrollView } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

<ScrollView style={{flex:1}}>
<View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection:'row', justifyContent: 'center', }}>

///// Place contents here

</View>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: i tried it and it made all my items disappear

Comment: Please try my amended answer (I added a view )

Comment: unfortunately, no luck. It still hides all my items. I tried removing the flex:1 next to scrollview and that seems to make my items reappear. However, still no scrolling

Comment: Please see a fully workable Flatlist which can scroll here: https://snack.expo.io/MFn07jwBT  , I have also added additional text after the Flatlist to show you the scrollView function

Answer (score 0):

Try `ScrollView` instead of `FlatList`. This will help you.
`ScrollView` renders all its react child components at once, but this has a performance downside.

```
<SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
<ScrollView style={styles.scrollView}>
data={array}
renderItem={({item}) => ( 
  <Text style={styles.item}>{item}</Text>
  )}
</ScrollView>
</SafeAreaView>
```

styles:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
flex: 1,
marginTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
},
scrollView: {
  marginHorizontal: 20,
},
item: {
  color:'black',
  fontSize:25,

},

});
```

Comment: i got an error saying "text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component. I worked around it a bit and tried to use scrollview even with a random text block. But still no scrolling

Comment: It's because of not adding styles related to `Text`. I added that now give it a try.

Comment: You have to import `ScrollView` and `SafeAreaView` from `react-native`

Comment: i did and still no luck. I have no clue why it wont work